# How to get build logs of a binder session

Tags: logging, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Binder hosted at www.mybinder.org is a service for launching Jupyter notebooks  online.

- When launching a notebook the  `Build logs` and a `nbviewer` preview are displayed.
- Once launched the Jupyter session is displayed.

Is there a way to access the  `Build logs` after the Binder session as started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no way. However, the best way to debug builds is to install [repo2docker](https://repo2docker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) locally and build things on your machine. repo2docker is the underlying tech that MyBinder and other Binderhubs use.

Other resources that may help:

- [Debug binder builds faster with repo2docker](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/tip-debug-binder-builds-faster-with-repo2docker/54)
- [a Binder GUI for easily launching local Jupyter containers](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/a-new-binder-gui-for-launching-local-containers/2705)

Other resources integrated with JupyterHub that may help:

- [Repo2DockerSpawner for JupyterHub](https://github.com/ideonate/repo2dockerspawner) specifically points out it streams logs of the build and "Logs are also passed on to the /spawn-pending/ logs page", see more about it [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/repo2dockerspawner-alternative-version/3584).
- [repo2dockerspawner - A JupyterHub Spawner that builds images dynamically](https://github.com/yuvipanda/repo2dockerspawner), this is the heart of the "The Littlest Binder", see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/would-a-the-littlest-binder-be-useful/1041/13?u=fomightez). [This post](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/repo2dockerspawner-alternative-version/3584) says it does much the same as [Repo2DockerSpawner for JupyterHub](https://github.com/ideonate/repo2dockerspawner); however, the documentation is presently sparse, and so I cannot comment directly on how it handles the logs.